# Make a download button redirect to a page?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a script resembling a page protector / redirecting links.
It is in the directory:

> /ROOT/redirect

When we add a link in front of it, as in the example below:

> http://mysite.net.ex/redirect/?url=linkthedownloadpage

It redirects after 15 seconds for the link.

But I wanted to know how to show a download button at the bottom of this page to link. Parecido like this:

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_ZguH4ax2gDs/TNm9hf3URiI/AAAAAAAAAFQ/rYgn5MOzfzo/s1600/folder-download.png

How do I do this?

Here is the script of my page, if someone can give me better, thanks:

http://jsfiddle.net/JZ5pu/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a total mess. Try tidying it up first.

Afterwards, try changing your function AtualizaTempo() to this:

```
function AtualizaTempo() {
  tempo = document.getElementById("div_tempo").innerHTML
  tempo = parseInt(tempo)
  tempo--
  if (tempo>0) {
    document.getElementById("div_tempo").innerHTML = tempo
    setTimeout('AtualizaTempo()', 1000)
  } else {
    div=document.getElementById('download_link');
    a=document.createElement('a');
    div.appendChild(a);
    a.href='[here goes your link]'

    img=document.createElement('img');
    a.appendChild(img);
    img.src='[here goes URL to the image]';
    img.border='0';
  }
}
```

Then, in the bottom of your page where you want the image to appear, just insert:

```
<div id="download_link"></div>
```

You could also make the link harder to read for an average user, if you used some sort of encoding. The simpliest one that comes in mind is just escaping it URL style. (See [this link](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/encode-decode.html) for example).
The line with href in AtualizaTempo() then becomes:

```
a.href=unescape('[here goes your URL escaped string]');
```

Hope this helps.

By the way did you use Google Translator?

Comment: Konecnyyes  I used the google translator.

But I can not add the download button on the page, the page could do for me?
It may be a new blank page and no countdown timer. Only she can redirect the link, and you see the download button. (I just want to add adsense ads around the button)